# How to generate a random number in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, what is the name of the function that returns a randomly generated floating point number between 0 and 1, left inclusive and right exclusive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`drand48`](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/LIBRARY/libc/SATS/DOCUGEN/HTML/stdlib.html#drand48) function from the standard library. See [this snippet](https://glot.io/snippets/ekbekok616) for a working example.